# Pylint error in Visual Studio Code Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this Unable to import 'dataImport' pylint(import-error).

How do I resolve this?

Attached is my codes:

```
import saveFile
import dataImport

dataImport.read_csv('income.csv')
saveFile.educationGraph()
saveFile.ageGraph()
saveFile.YrsInCompanyGraph()
saveFile.yrsCurrRoleGraph()
saveFile.workYrsGraph()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEBAV.png)

Comment: Your system doesn't seem to have `dataImport` in the first place. Install it first via `pip install dataimport` and then retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed the module "`dataImport`" using `pip` in VSCode,(`pip install dataImport`) I still couldn't use it, so I found it in the package installation directory and found that it was installed by default with the name "`dataimport`", so VSCode could not find the package "`dataImport`".

[image]

solve:

We can rename the package name to "`dataImport`", or use "`import dataimport`":

[image]

In addition, please confirm that the module "`dataimport`" is successfully installed in the currently selected VSCode environment. (`pip list`)